# Add a stack navigator inside a tab navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to add TrackList screen to navigate to TrackDetail. I have mine like this, but I know there is an issue. I can't seem to know how to add that functionality to the tracklist.

```
<Tab.Navigator>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackList" component={TrackListScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={SigninScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="TrackCreate" component={TrackCreateScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have `Tab.Screen` elements inside `Tab.Navigator`. So, just wrap you stacks into another component first. For example, create your stack component like:

```
    const TrackListStack = () => {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackList" component={TrackListScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={SigninScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

and add the component into your navigator:

```
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="TrackListStack" component={TrackListStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="TrackCreate" component={TrackCreateScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Another thing to avoid double app (screen) title, we can headershown false. This worked great in my situation. Thanks! <Tab.Screen name="TrackListStack" component={TabWithStackNavigatorWrapper} options={{headerShown:false}} />

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
An appropriate way would be to use this way

```
<Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="TabListScreen" component={TabListScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="AnotherTabListScreen" component={AnotherTabListScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>


<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="TabNavigator">
  <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
  <Stack.Screen name="ScreenDetail" component={ScreenDetail} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not wrap `Stack` element inside into `Tab` navigation, you need to create separate `function` for `Stack navigation` and you can add this `Stacknavigation` function into Tab Navigation Like :-

```
 const StackNavigation = () => {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackList" component={TrackListScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={SigninScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };

    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="TrackListStack" component={StackNavigation} />
      <Tab.Screen name="TrackCreate" component={TrackCreateScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```